# Transferring Data from Excel to a PDF

Tags: javascript, excel, visual-studio, pdf

I am in the midst of transferring data from an excel sheet to a PDF document with mapping of fields.  This one field is kicking my arse.   It's properly pulling the value but my form has the % sign listed on the tail end.   Even though it is pulling 0.03 its being expressed as a percentage.  I just need it to say "3" since the form has the percentage sign and that is what management wants since it is a legal maintenance proposal/contract.

```
Set retAcro = jso.getField("annualEscalation")
        retAcro.Value = CStr(.Range("I17"))
```

My Excel sheet is giving the value
[image: Excel Sheet (Input)]

This is the result output on the PDF.
[image: PDF]

Comment: multiply by 100?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Format of the field on the PDF (template) to "percentage"